# Why do we ever need `hasArray()` method in CharBuffer?

Tags: java, nio

CharBuffer has methods `array()` and `hasArray()`.

Why do we ever need `hasArray()`?

After `CharBuffer buf = CharBuffer.allocate(20)`, `hasArray()` is always true, before - we cannot use buf reference b/c it is uninitialized.

Comment: @markspace There is no `CharBuffer.allocateDirect()`... That's just for `ByteBuffer` afaik.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition for `hasArray` is

```
(hb != null) && !isReadOnly
```

---

`isReadOnly` changes if you use `asReadOnlyBuffer`

```
CharBuffer.allocate(20).asReadOnlyBuffer();
```

for example.
So yes, we need it.

---

Take this line

```
final CharBuffer cb = instance.getCharBuffer(...);
```

Is it read-only or not? Does it hold a valid `char[]` array? We don't really know. If we do

```
cb.array();
```

and it is a read-only Buffer, we get a `ReadOnlyBufferException`.
If it isn't backed by a `char[]` array we get a `UnsupportedOperationException`.

So what we *might* do is

```
if (cb.hasArray()) {
   final char[] arr = cb.array();
}
```

Now we are `Exception`-safe.
Also, you can be sure Oracle/OpenJDK/whateverJDK engineers know what they're doing ;)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but:

```
System.out.println(ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(100).asCharBuffer().hasArray());
```

returns `false`.

And even if it didn't, it isn't known beforehand how the buffer has been retrieved. You could imagine that the OS allocates the buffer and that it is just used by Java, e.g. when opening a text file. That you cannot directly allocate it yourself is inconsequential.

Besides that `hasArray()` is a [function defined in the parent class `Buffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/Buffer.html#hasArray()), so it *needs* to be there for that reason alone.

---

As the other answer indicates, retrieving an array that is read only accessible would also return false, from the documentation:

> `true` if, and only if, this buffer is backed by an array and is not read-only

this makes sense as you don't want to pass a read only buffer, only to have it altered by somebody retrieving the backing array and writing data to the array that way; Java arrays are always mutable after all.